# jQuery extracting attribute id from html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I'm using a piece of code that is supposed to extract the value from a tag in html. It works fine with a single word for example 'desk' but it doesn't work with an id composed by two or more words: `<a href='#' id='hello world'> Hello world </a>`

In this cases I'm only getting the word 'hello' and not 'hello world'.
Here's my code:

```
 $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){ 
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
     });
```

Is there any way to extract a multiple word id? Thanks.

Comment: IDs with spaces are invalid: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global

Comment: Spaces shouldn't be in your ids, but depending on your browser it [may work anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/FuM3s/) (but get rid of the spaces)

Comment: which browser(s) did you use for the tests? Chrome returns all the words. That said, spaces in id are against the specs, as others have said.

Comment: I thought I've seen them all but I've never seen anyone two words used in the id attribute until now lol. If you must, do id="hello-world", then parse it with .attr('id').replace('-','')

Answer (score 4):

The `id` attribute cannot contain spaces [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#the-id-attribute), but even if it could, the [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute is a better place to store generic data.  `id`s are used for *identifying* elements.

html:

```
<li data-value="hello world"></li>
```

js:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){ 
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: it's not working also.. I'm inserting the values dinamically. It's there any problem?

Comment: Your original question has the property in the `<a>` element - `this` would refer to the `<li>` so you need to make sure it is on the correct element.

Answer (score -1):

ID only supports one value. In that case, use a class.

Comment: It's not entirely correct.  OP wants *one value* with spaces in it but the class attribute stores *multiple values* that are *space delimited*.

Comment: Technically it only supports one value but no one can stop anyone from using it n-times. It's incorrect but it will render fine. This answer seems partially correct but it lacks proper explanation on why. Maybe this would have been better as a comment instead of an actual answer.

Answer (score -1):

ID should be a unique value, and thus only have one value in it. Using spaces is bad, I would replace them with underscores. If you need multiple values, you'll probably want to use classes instead.

However, this works like you are asking for.

HTML:

```
<li id='hello_world'> Hello world </li>
```

JS:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){ 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
});
```

Comment: don't see why this is getting downvoted. it details the proper use of the `id` attributes, suggests a better alternative, and in the event the OP absolutely has to use the `id` attribute, provides a clear example that shows it works.

Comment: As @Dennis has shown in his answer - data attributes are a much cleaner solution to this problem.

Comment: As the standard says "Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements." It is entirely dependent on the OP's implementation and requirements as to whether or not the tag/attribute he desires is something more appropriate than `data-*` or not.

Comment: He is trying to extract a value from a tag. The value in this example being "hello world", not "hello_world". Adding a workaround to using the ID attribute inappropriately is not a good solution. It is better to use the data attributes which were created for this sort of situation.

Comment: Actually he's trying to extract the value of an attribute from a tag. But whatever at this point.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant extract the value of an attribute. Which should definitely not be the ID.